# How to add control above a Gridrow

Tags: c#, wpf

Here I have the XAML as follows.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="a label here" Height="30" Background="LightBlue"/>
    <Grid Background="LightCoral">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="first col"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="cbox"/>
        <Button Content="showerror" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Now I want to add a control, the label "error!" above the Combobox "cbox".

[image]

Rather than using Popup, is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: you could change the background color of the cell to indicate an error and have a legend next to the grid explaining the colors..

Comment: implement validaton for your data and add custom Validation.ErrorTemplate to combobox

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you searching for:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="a label here" Height="30" Background="LightBlue"/>
        <Grid Background="LightCoral">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Content="Error"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  Content="first col"/>
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Button Content="showerror" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liTV9.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want to use an extra new row to display it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Canvas.

```
<Canvas>
    <TextBlock Background="WhiteSmoke" Foreground="Red" Text="error" Canvas.Left="110" Canvas.Top="20"/>
    <Canvas.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Canvas}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsShown}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Style>
</Canvas>
```